# A singular verb instead of the plural one

Tags: verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is “there're” (similar to “there's”) a correct contraction?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/is-therere-similar-to-theres-a-correct-contraction)

Why it is that in some cases native speakers use a singular verb instead of the plural?

Eg., There's times like....

Here's your shoes...