# Is there a contraction for "where are" like "where's" for "where is"?

Tags: verb-agreement, contractions, grammatical-number

What is a contraction for *where are*?

I wanted to ask "Where are the keys?" but want to use a contraction.

Do I have to just say *Where are*, or can I say *Where's* and it's understood?

Comment: "Where's the keys?" is informal. It may be ungrammatical in a strict sense, but is accepted in speech and informal writing. Also, when the subject is plural (or even whole list) but is considered in its entirety rather than its elements, the singular verb is understandable: *Such traffic chaos! Where's the **rules**?*

Answer (score 4):

"Where're the keys?"  =  "Where are the keys?"

"Where's the key?"  =  "Where is the key?"

Your question revolves around the number of the word *key*.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking there might be a contraction for Where are, it just didn't sound right. Now it does!

Comment: @Jonathan Spirit You can also say, of course: 'Where're you going?, or 'Where's he off to?'

Answer (score 3):

You will commonly hear utterances such as *Where's the keys* or *There's cookies in the jar* or *Here's the answers to the quiz*. David Crystal has a useful article on this topic. He states that *where are* and *where're* are "*much more awkward to pronounce*".

He continues:

> So what is the grammatical rule involved in the informal cases?
>   Basically, the verb is agreeing with the meaning of the following noun
>   phrase and not with its form. The distinction is summarised by calling
>   the former principle *notional concord* and the latter principle
>   *grammatical concord*. Traditional grammars always insist on people
>   following grammatical concord, but spontaneous speech contains many
>   examples of notional concord taking place.

As to the OP's last question, it is difficult to imagine a context in which you would be misunderstood for asking *Where's the keys?* etc. rather than *Where are the keys?* - unless you misheard *keys* as *key*.

[David Crystal: Safety in numbers](http://www.davidcrystal.com/?fileid=-3990) (.pdf)

Comment: More on this at [Is “there're” (similar to “there's”) a correct contraction?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/is-therere-similar-to-theres-a-correct-contraction)

Comment: @Kris, that's what comes of not proofreading correctly after reducing the slightly hyperbolic "excellent article" to "useful article".