# Is the question "where is Elmo's legs?" correct usage?

Tags: grammar, questions, verb-agreement

Is

> 1. Where is Elmo's legs?

correct usage?

And how about:

> 2. Where's Elmo's legs?

Is that more or less acceptable, and why?

Comment: *are*. "Where *are* Elmo's legs?" They're connecting his torso to his feet.

Comment: This brings to mind [this answer](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/2a/14/89/2a14891391c60f3f9b868b86a78fe5fc.jpg) to the question of what's wrong with Kermit. :-)

Comment: I would lump plural *where's* with plural *there's*, for which see *[“There Is”/“There are” depends on plurality of the first list element or not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/)*, *[Is “there're” (similar to “there's”) a correct contraction?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12865)*, and *[“There’s” or “There are”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77089)*.

Answer (score 5):

"Legs" is plural, and to be grammatically correct, the question should be "Where are Elmo's legs?" However, "where's" (rather than "where is") has definitely crept into the vernacular when asking about either singular or plural nouns.

Comment: I think "Where is [plural noun]?" is a lot less accepted than "Where's [plural noun]?"