# Is there a contraction known as the're?

Tags: american-english, british-english, contractions

Recently, one of my relatives started studying the English Language and she came to discuss that the contraction of **there are** can also be written as **the're**  because that's they way she learnt it at school. I am assuming this new contraction is wrong, but I am not a native English speaker and I studied English grammar long time ago, so I would like to know if this new form is right or wrong. I base my assumption on the following points:

1. The contraction of **there are** is **there're** but it is rarely used because of the double /r/ pronunciation.
2. According to the answer from [Is "there're" (similar to "there's") a correct contraction?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/is-therere-similar-to-theres-a-correct-contraction?lq=1) , the contraction **there're** is correct but it is more often to use **there's**.

All suggestions and examples are welcome :)

Comment: You can pronounce the contracted form of *there are* as *there* (although most people don't), but the spelling should be *"there're"*.

Comment: Yep, "there're" is pronounced roughly "there-ur", though the "ur" part is highly truncated and often completely swallowed.

Comment: "There's" is more common only because the subject of a sentence is more commonly singular. In writing, use "there're" to replace "there are" and "there's" to replace "there is".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no; there is no contraction such as the're. I am sure it is a misunderstanding.

Comment: So, if this is a misunderstanding I should talk with the teacher or do something since many colleagues from my relative are learning this "new" contraction.

Comment: Yes, I assert with certainty that there is no such contraction. Alas, I cannot prescribe a course of action to correct your relative's mistake.