# Plural vs singular

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I find many Americans say there's a lot of people/cars/programs....is that correct or should "there's" be replaced with there are?? This question just keeps bugging me quite a bit

Comment: The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there%27s+a+lot%2Cthere+are+a+lot%2Cthere+is+a+lot&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20%27s%20a%20lot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20are%20a%20lot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20is%20a%20lot%3B%2Cc0) shows an even choice between 'there's a lot/there is a lot/ there are a lot'. BrE seems to favour 'there is a lot'. (Link playing up - just hit the 'Search lots of books' key.)

Comment: Also see *[Is “there're” (similar to “there's”) a correct contraction?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12865)*

Answer (score -1):

The argument/ assumption seems to be that the focus in

> There … **a lot of** people/cars/programs …

is on *a lot* which is apparently singular.

Now recall that *a lot* is synonymous with *lots*:

> There … **lots of** people/cars/programs …

With exactly the same meaning.

Of course, we'd use *are* in "There … **lots of** people/cars/programs …".

It's a quirk of grammar that a seemingly singular phrase is a synonym of a patently plural word, so that grammar books always insist that it should be:

> There **are a lot of** people/cars/programs …

This needs to be followed in writing. In speech, people find it more logical (makes better sense) to say ***is a lot*** of things because of the article *a*.

---

<sup>Note: I'm not relating this question to the identical one on ELL or the ones right here on ELU because the answers there are either incorrect or incomplete.</sup>

Comment: I don't think the use of "there's" is really related to the presence of "a lot". I can say "There's three cars" or "There's tons of cars" just as well.

Comment: @sumelic Kris is making the point that **...a lot of...** begins with the indefinite article hence native speakers find it more natural to use the verb in the singular.  It's a valid point, not sure if it deserves a downvote. Not sure if it's worth upvoting either. If Kris finds the answers in the original question either incorrect or incomplete, see footnote, maybe they should post their answer there.

Comment: [***There's some people*** *in this world who you can just love and love and love no matter what.*](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/200025-there-s-some-people-in-this-world-who-you-can-just) ― John Green (American author)