# Contracted forms and their limitations

Tags: contractions

Are there any limitations as to contracted forms of auxiliaries in English? In other words, can we only use contracted forms after personal pronouns or we can also use them after nouns such as in: **I'm afraid the house'll be too small for us** or **My parents're already here**?

Comment: This is too broad. There are several questions that cover this already. Look under the [highest voted contraction questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contractions?tab=Votes), for example a question about [there're](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/is-therere-similar-to-theres-a-correct-contraction).

Comment: There are actual contracted forms and ones that writers make up and use to reflect speech. Not the same thing **at all**. Both of yours are made up by the writers.